# Why does my VSIX not install on Visual Studio Professional?

Tags: vsix

I have created a VSIX that is supposed to be installable on either Visual Studio 2013 Professional or higher and/or Visual Studio 2015 Community or higher. When people install with Visual Studio 2013 Professional I get the following error on the log (relevant bits):

```
SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5,)
Supported Products : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
Version : [12.0,)
References      : 
Searching for applicable products...
Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Integrated)
Found installed product - Global Location
Found installed product - ssms
VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

I have taken out the dates on the left.

I was thinking that 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community', Version : [12.0,)
would have supported 'Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013', but then I would not expect to get this error.

What are the settings required to allow a vsix extension to target Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2015 Community?

(I would prefer to allow community for 2013, but my understanding is that version does not support VSIX. If it matters this is a project template with a Wizard.)

Comment: Use pro - and vs 2013 community supports extensions.

Comment: @ErikEJ - I am not following. The person trying to install has installed product 'Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013'. This works on Visual Studio 2015 Community and Professional, but not on Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013. I would have thought that the [12.0,) would support 2013, but5 it does not. What am I missing? thanks...

Comment: In other words - please share the relevant part of your .vsixmanifest file, if you have written "Community" in that file, it wont work

Comment: `  <Installation>
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" Version="[12.0,]" />
  </Installation>
  <Dependencies>
    <Dependency Id="Microsoft.Framework.NDP" DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework" d:Source="Manual" Version="[4.5,)" />
  </Dependencies>`

Comment: Clearly, I have written 'Community', but I need to work for Community. I also want it to work for things higher than Community.
On other bit of info, for other people, particularly those with VS 2015, this **did** install without issue on VS 2013 Professional.

Comment: Change the installation taget id to .Pro

Answer (score 0):

Should repair the Visual Studio or modify the packages if some missing updates

Comment: I don't think this is a useful suggestion - the solution was provided in the comments, and also this is a question from 8 years ago.